# Can WCF service with net.tcp bindings be accessed over internet?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, net.tcp

I have developed a simple WCF service (hosted in a Windows Service) quite similar to following msdn article.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647180.aspx#Step1

How should i deploy it so that it can be accessed over internet using tcp?

Comment: Put it on an internet-facing server where the port you're using is accessible (i.e. not blocked by a firewall).

Comment: Thanks martin & sorry for coming back too late.. I have hosted that service on IIS7 and i am able to call it by making a test client on my machine. However, i would like to know if that service can be called through internet say, from an ios device. Note that i am using nettcp & mextcp bindings here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is that it will use a different port than HTTP (80) and may be blocked by some firewalls (probably most if not all).

Answer (score 1):

TCP binding is used only when the clients are from the same network. If your clients are outside of your network you will have to use HTTP protocol like basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding.

In real time application you have multiple service endpoints with different kind of bindings like for backoffice and stand alone application you use netTcpBinding and for internet application you use wsHttpBinding.